# How do I remove characters from a query field that cause Excel to interpret the field as more than one column or as a function

Tags: excel, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am stuck having to query a SQL Server database that is mimicking SQL server 2000 database and no way around it.

I have a large result set of 5 fields.  The last field is a memo field.  The result set is so large in SSMS 2012 that I cannot select them all with headers.  So I have to save to Excel csv format.  In doing so it interprets data in the 5th field as either a function (“-“, “+”, “(space) –“, “(space)+”, etc at the beginning) or as multiple columns for various reasons.

So far I have

```
replace(ltrim(rtrim(memo)), ',', ' ') as Memo
```

This, of course, trims beginning and end and replaces commas with spaces.  I do not want to have to build nested replaces unless I must.  This is for a large audit report that is not run often so I can, if need be, use a function.

Is there a good way to make a field like this compliant with Excel so that Excel will just keep that field as one column?  I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: You could use VBA to do `.Replace` in that column?

Comment: One solution presented by a coworker was append double quotes to the beginning and end.  This worked but I am curious if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the correct method is to append double quotes to the beginning and the end of the field value returned in the query.  As I am having to right-click and output to Excel this methods works and Excel does not misinterpret the intent.